# audio streaming plugin but with no save option?

Tags: plugins

I need to publish a audio file that I want to make available to

- listen and
- not to download

any idea how to do it? Is there any free WP plugin for that?

Something where user cannot save the audo using any webbrowser plugin like DownloadHelper etc.

Comment: Native support for audio in WordPress now.

Comment: @BradDalton: But would such audio be "downloadable" by let's say DownloadHelper and others?

Comment: You could include a link to it before or after the video or use a plugin to manage the download.

Comment: I don't understand. What I want is to make it "hard" to save the audio file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at either [Audio Player](http://wpaudioplayer.com/) or [XSPF](http://www.boriel.com/software/plugins/the-wordpress-xspf-player-plugin/)? I've had good success with both of those.

Comment: no, I haven't. Do they have the feature 'no save'?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. They're basically Flash wrappers around MP3 files and thus obscure the actual location of your audio files...

Comment: There are players that allow you to save (I don't mean that they have 'save button' somewhere) the file and some players have some kind of better protection so user cannot save the audio file. I am after the one that will make it harder for the listener to save the audio file.

Comment: Radek, are you talking about not being able to sniff the http sessions, e.g. you want it to be like hulu but with audio? I haven't seen anything WordPress specific for this, but with a flash player you'll need an encrypted stream, which requires Flash Media Server.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought of something like Soundcloud? - http://soundcloud.com/

Like youtube but audio files instead of video, easily implemented in to wordpress as it's a case of copy and paste the coding.

Comment: I can save the file from soundcloud.com using DownloadHelper. The major requirement is that user cannot save the audio file.